# Importing existing Flash .xfl & .as files into Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I've been working with Flash CS5 (for a very short time..).
I got a XFL file, its library files and AS files in a directory.
I would like to use Flash Builder 4(FB) for editing AS files, running the compiled SWF and profiling.

When I created a New->ActionScript project in FB, I could edit the AS files but didn't know how to link the XFL file and run them.
When I created a New->Flash Professional Project, I was prompted for a XFL file, and although the chosen XFL file and the AS files are in a same directory, the AS files are not automatically included in the project. I couldn't find a way to add exiting files in the project either. I'm fairly new to this Flash & Flex Platform and not getting this..

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **New** → **Flash Professional Project**.

Flash Builder will automatically create a new ActionScript file, and you will probably want to use yours instead.  Right-click on your project, **Properties**, **ActionScript Build Path**, **Source Path**.  Then remove the folder which was added and instead, add yours, which in your case should be `.`.  In the lower part of the panel, you have to change the **Main source folder** to your actual source folder.  Press `OK` so that it refreshes the project.

Now go back in your project properties, **ActionScript Applications**, press `Add` and select your actual main ActionScript file.  Press `OK`, then select it again and `Set it as Default`.

You should now be able to open your ActionScript file and build it inside Flash Builder by selecting the `Publish Movie` option. It will automatically open Flash Professional to build the project.

Note that the Flash convention is to use a `src` folder in your project for ActionScript files. I suggest you use a `ui` folder for your .xfl and .fla documents.

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!! I now know the very existence of the settings you told me. I followed your advise and created src & ui folders, and it worked :) I tried to preserve my original folder structure, but because of some errors in Flash Builder, I couldn't use . or .. or \ for the main source folder.

Comment: When I tried to publish from Flash Builder, Flash couldn't locate the sources files and raised many errors. I fixed it by Flash CS 5->ui.xfl->ActionScript Settings->source path->add new path (.\src).